# GAE and JDO: any recommended techniques to work with persistance manager?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

The basic example of using JDO in App Engine documentation is really simple:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

Employee e = new Employee("Alfred", "Smith", new Date());

try {
    pm.makePersistent(e);
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

But in my opinion, it's kind of annoying to get and close persistence manager every time I want to access the storage, there's a lot of redundant code. So what would you recommend to avoid that?

For example, I came across a solution which recommended getting the PM in filter and attaching it to the `request` so I could access it directly from any servlet. The PM would be closed by the filter automatically as well. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do it in a DAO layer where you can keep the boilerplate code out of your business logic
2. Is it *really* that big a deal? I mean, typing stuff isn't the hard part of programming :)
3. I wouldn't use JDO personally. Objectify is much easier as it was designed for appengine specifically

Comment: 1. Thank you, I'll read something more about this approach.
2. Well, I don't know much about standard programming techniques (that's why I ask) but I think that writing 5 lines of code when it could be only 1 every time I would like to access the datastore isn't exactly perfect. The code is also imho less readable.
3. I've chosen JDO in case I would like to switch platform in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the PM in filter and closing that PM after work is done (finally clause inside doFilter) is a good approach. This keeps the code clean, easy to maintain and easy to change if in future you are moving to JPA for instance